# Regex to identify a encoded string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to get the value of the SAMLRequest in the below implementation. To do this I need to know the exact Regex which suits for this. Please share me the exact Regex to to identify the Value of the SAMLRequest Field..

```
string value = @" <html><head><title>Testing...</title></head><body><form method='POST' name='hiddenform' action='https:/gmail.com'><input type='hidden' name='SAMLRequest' value='SGVsbG8gV29ybGQuLkkgYW0gZ29pbmcgdG8gVFJZIGVuY29kaW5n==' /><input type='hidden' name='RelayState' value='cec5effd-7fb4-40ba-a7ac-795917b5d069' /><noscript><p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></noscript></form><script language='javascript'>window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script></body></html> <html><head>";
```

Any Help on this highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not a very reliable way to extract information from html and should not be used.  Let me explain.

You could use a regex like this `(?<=name='SAMLRequest' value=')[^']+` which would seem to work on this particular test case.

However, it is a very brittle solution.  Imagine if html changed from `'` to `"` or re-arranged the attributes like (`<input type='hidden' name='SAMLRequest' value='PHNh...` changes to `<input name="SAMLRequest" type="hidden" value="PHNh...`)

Then your little time saver (by using regex instead of an html parser) becomes trouble.  Good luck!